# Very Basic SymPy Error

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I'm trying to learn SymPy. I've written the following and its throwing an error. I haven't even gotten to anything complicated...

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

string = "10x+4=7"
#equation = raw_input("Enter an equation")

left, right = string.split('=')
string = left + "-(" + right + ")";
print string
x = Symbol('x')
print solve(string, x)
```

This code is throwing an error:

```
raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse u'10x+4-(7)'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very basic indeed.

Multiplication in `python` is achieved with the `*` character.

Hence, you should set `string` as follows:

```
string = "10*x+4=7"
```

If you'd like to auto-insert the `*` character in front of every x in your equations, you can define a function like this one to do the job:

```
def insert_asterisks(equation):
    return equation.replace('x', '*x')
```

Here's an example use of this function:

```
In [16]: string = "10x+4=7"

In [17]: string = insert_asterisks(string)

In [18]: print string
10*x+4=7
```

Comment: Is there a way to auto insert * when a #x appears?

Comment: Thanks! The only problem would be if there is a single variable x. Would something like equation.replace('\dx', '\d*x') work? @dbliss

Comment: Actually, re.sub would probably be better for this, right?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "a single variable x," but your example makes it look like you have some differential equations.  in any event, if you have exceptions to the "asterisk before every x" rule, then yeah, using regular expressions is the way to go.  good luck!  if you get stuck, i'd say you could start a new question -- your original question here seems to be resolved.